Why does "vmstat" disagree with "free" after a while?

This is not a duplicate of Why do free and vmstat display different info (total and used)

There is probably some bug or incompatibility in vmstat
When running vmstat for a while it starts to disagree with free.  This increases over time until the output of vmstat is completely unusable crap
on the affected values.
This leeds to a combination of following questions:

Can anybody else confirm this?
Where to find more information about this and what causes it?
How to repair properly?


Note that I report this here early, so before I have more information.
And I do not need help because it is just an annoyance.

Infos
$ uname -a
Linux (redacted) 6.1.0-20-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.85-1 (2024-04-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm

$ dpkg -l procps | cat
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  procps         2:4.0.2-3    amd64        /proc file system utilities

# dpkg --verify procps
??5?????? c /etc/sysctl.conf
#

The problem
When started vmstat and free agree, but there already can be some slight bias:
$ free; vmstat 3 2; free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        32650568    26608268     7577824      411648      699696     6042300
Swap:       31457276     3994720    27462556

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
30  6 3994464 7575240  56804 643064  179  189  4028  1874 2317 22945 64 24  7  5  0
 5  5 3994464 7575240  56804 643064   19    0 249612 24786 12070 57996 21 31 25 23  0

               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        32650568    26661436     7517940      411696      708000     5989132
Swap:       31457276     3994208    27463068

This might be normal on a busy machine, but I think, vmstat already miscalculates these values, such that after a while, the errors add up until the values become completely out of bounds:
$ vmstat 3
[after an hour or so]
 3  5 5745880 3422064  35576 220220   19    0 226691  9334 24105 61618 22 30 29 19  0
 4  5 5745880 3422064  35576 220220   16    0 155941 38951 16270 54930 19 24 31 26  0
10  5 5745880 3422064  35576 220220    1   21 253594 11063 14066 50767 19 29 28 24  0
 4  2 5745880 3422064  35576 220220    0    0 128184 34534 24439 51341 18 20 32 30  0

While in another terminal (following ran in parallel of the above lines):
$ free; vmstat 3 2
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        32650568    28221708     5778984      401352      950904     4428860
Swap:       31457276     3952224    27505052
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 5  3 3952224 5777424 234584 716932  179  189  4032  1874 2316 22942 64 24  7  5  0
 2  3 3952224 5777424 234584 716932   17    0 230215  8339 17784 55440 21 29 29 20  0

Compare the both values
5745880 3422064  35576 220220 (utterly wrong)
3952224 5777424 234584 716932 (probably real)

As you can clearly see, the numbers have no more connection to any reality after some while.

I tried to figure this out myself, but in my limited time I failed to even find a trace to a hint what might cause this (or how to fix it).  So I report it here until I am able to answer this myself unless somebody else nukes my question, what usually happens quite too often.  However due to all the current (global) crisis it is very unlikely that I find (excess) time to dive into this deeply enough to find the root cause.

As a mitigation my recommendation is

Do not trust the 4 values swpd, free, buff and cache in vmstat at all
Run a while sleep-loop around the command free to gather the real values

Notes

I do not open a bug on Debian because I currently was unable to reproduce this (as I haven't tried due to lack of time) on another machine to make up a good report
It is unknown when this effect started, but I think it is relatively new

I am tracking this 4 weeks now
Perhaps it is due to the kernel?  (it is 2 security patches old)
The machine only boots into a newer kernel when something else needs a reboot!


Perhaps it needs a very busy server, perhaps even with a certain workload

This one runs ZFS, CouchDB and VMs (and more, flawlessly)


There are no anomalies nor hardware defects known currently

Except for the vmstat anomaly
And some usual badly written standard programs, of course, which are unlikely to even be able to cause this effect



